# "Poison" is to "poisoned" as "venom" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy, participles

As the title says, *poison* is to *poisoned* as *venom* is to what?

I tried looking up *venomed* but it means something different.

Is there such a word?

Comment: could it be "venomous"?

Comment: @Mustafa No, that correlates to "poisonous".

Comment: No. It's *envenomed*.

Comment: @Robusto: envenomed is the past of envenom, which doesn't mean to poison. It means to make poisonous. Therefore, envenomed means "made poisonous"

Comment: @Pubby: [Your question has been asked on yahoo](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110831170053AAsaAaP). There are a lot of interesting answers there.

Comment: @Pubby, I took it as adj to adj combination. I am unaware of something like *venom***ed**

Comment: @Armen: So does "poisoned" ...

Comment: @Robusto: Poisoned can mean that, sure. But poisoned also means "rendered ill by poison". Envenomed does not have that meaning, does it?

Comment: To clarify, I was asking about the illness. I should have been more clear in the post, although having both answers is still useful.

Comment: @Armen: Who cares? The question was ambiguous, so the answer I gave works.

Comment: The question is pointless. Just because *venom* exists as a particular subset of "types of poison" doesn't mean there should be a special word for *poisoned by venom* as opposed to *poisoned by any other substance apart from venom*.

Comment: ...seek and ye shall find! [Here's an example](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E55xNYgA0OQC&q=toxined&dq=toxined&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ehMvT4zOI9SA8gOI3sT-Dg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwATgU) of *toxined* used to mean *poisoned by toxins*. But I can't say I really endorse such usage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, **venomed** exists and you can find it [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/venom?q=venomed#venom__3). In literature I have seen the expression *venomed arrows*, meaning *covered with venom*, but according to [this source](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.com/definitions/venomed?cx=partner-pub-0939450753529744%3Av0qd01-tdlq&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&q=venomed&sa=Search#906) it also means **poisoned** as the past participle of the verb **venom**.

Comment: I said in my answer that I haven't seen venomed use as a verb but I think you've made a good point!

Answer (score 11):

In biology, the term *envenomated* (past participle of *envenomate*) is used for this; Google Books turns up uses like:

- Distribution of Venoms in **Envenomated** Animals
- Called strike-induced chemosensory searching (SICS), this phenomenon facilitates location of an **envenomated** rodent which might wander several meters from the snake after the strike.
- The first experience is receiving a dry bite and not being **envenomated** at all.

<s>That said, I think I'd only use *envenomated* if the venom is actually delivered by a venomous animal (especially a snake, via bite). If, say, someone were to extract snake venom and use it to poison someone's drink, I think the recipient would be *poisoned*, not "envenomated".</s> ← **Edit:** Never mind, please disregard this paragraph. Firstly, snake venom isn't actually poisonous (though it's not a good idea to drink it, because if you happen to have a small cut or sore in your mouth or throat, the venom can get in that way). And secondly, "envenomated" is also used when scientists inject venom as part of an experiment, not just when it's delivered by the venomous animal.

Comment: 'envenomate' seems too long a word. The prefix 'en-' and the suffix '-ate' appear to perform the same function. I prefer 'envenom'.

Comment: @BarryBrown But they don't. A blade can be (poetically) _envenomed_ with poison. Evolution has gradually _envenomated_ some species. It didn't smear poison on them. They gradually developed mechanisms to produce poison.

Comment: I upvoted this xD but I've come to realize that it's wrong. It's a valid past tense for a verb of one context in which _venom_ can be discussed. It can't ever be used in answer to OP's question, though, because there's no way that the POISON:POISONED part works in this context. The evolutionary development of poison isn't _poisoning_ and the past tense of that process having happened would never be _poisoned_.

Comment: Edit: Upon further checking, I guess I'll still upvote it. Yeah, your sources _are_ using it to just mean _injected with venom_ + _I'm sciency_ and not to describe the evolutionary process.

Comment: I think the last paragraph stands correct within that context. You just might add the bit at the end about the additional "_we_ got the venom into the mouse" sense.

Answer (score 8):

To **envenom** someone or something is to make it poisonous or to add poison to it. So, if  using *poison* in the figurative sense of fouling, embittering, spoiling, etc. it would be acceptable, as in envenoming a relationship. It would not be suitable when using *poison* in the sense of murdering someone by poison, or adulterating something lethally.

Comment: I assumed (perhaps too presumptuously) that poison was being used in its obvious sense (that is 'to poison' as a snake would poison a child or as murderer would poison his/her victim). My interpretation of the word 'poison' found that 'venom' could also be a verb meaning the same as 'poison' in that context but that this use of 'venom' was archaic so we wouldn't make the comparison. However, I think your response points out that a comparison can be made if we are using 'poison' in a different sense (that is 'to envenom'). The answer may depend on the context in which the phrase is being used.

Comment: "The point envenomed too!  Then, venom, to thy work."

Comment: @Rachel Snakes don't have hands to poison children or anyone else. Snakes _bite_ children, after which they _are poisoned_ by the _venom_ in their blood.

Answer (score 2):

In the common usage, whereas if a person ingested *poison* he would be said to have been *poisoned,* if he received *venom* the perfect participle would depend on the delivery system: *bitten* by a snake, spider or biting insect, *stung* by a bee or scorpion or stinging insect.

Comment: Or just "poisoned"

Comment: @Oldcat not if you want to differentiate between lethal ingestion and toxic injection by an animal of some kind.

Comment: @Oldcat, no one is going to change the verb to differentiate lethal ingestion, but Mr Fink is nonetheless right that, no, you don't say a person with a beesting is poisoned, ever. You _could_ say someone with a severe amount of snake venom in their system has (passively) been poisoned, though. Still, more normal to vary by delivery: _He was poisoned by his children_, _he was bit by a snake_, _he got poisoned  by some berries/from a snakebite_.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it is that 'venom' and 'poison' are both nouns. They are also both verbs; however, in reality, we don't actually hear 'vemon' used as a verb. Some dictionary entries depict 'venom' only as a noun (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/venom) whereas those that depict 'venom' also as a verb tend to state that its usage as a verb is archaic (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/venom).

What I am getting at is that when we say 'poison is to poisoned' we are talking about 'poison' as a verb. Technically you could say 'as venom is to venomed' (http://verbs.woxikon.com/english-verbforms/venom.php); however, since 'venom' is only ever used as a noun, we are attempting to compare a verb ('poison') and a noun ('venom') in a manner that is incomparable. I cannot think of one native English speaker I know who would have ever heard the word 'venomed'. So whilst it may be grammatically correct, I don't think that you would draw this comparison if your comparison is related to usage as as opposed to grammatical technicalities (Thus, I look to usage to answer your question not to the few authorities that stipulate that 'venom' is an archaic verb.)

Some responses have mentioned the adjectives 'poisonous' and 'venomous'. We could indeed say that, 'poison is to poisonous as venom is to venomous' (noun --> adjective, noun --> adjective) since they are both nouns in the first instance (as opposed to 'poison' as a verb and 'venom' as a noun which is my interpretation of the phrase in question).

Comment: I know I've seen venomed once or twice before; but it's definitely not normal/common usage.

Answer (score 1):

**OP asked:**

> poison:poisoned::venom:_______???________

**The answer depends on the context**, because you've got words there that can be used as nouns, verbs, and adjectives and the verbs can involve actions, statuses, possession, etc.

**If we're doing Present-Tense Verb:Past-Tense Verb** as a grammar exercise, then [Irene's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57095/171986) is 100% right:

### **Poison:Poisoned::Venom:Venomed**

*Venomed* is the usual past tense of the verb [*to venom*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/222183) in its various [extremely uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+venoms%2C+it+envenoms%2C+it+envenomates&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) senses. They're *so* uncommon that in the wild you will find people actually writing [*venom-ed* and *venom'ed*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22venom-ed%22) to make it clear they know they're verbing a noun, even though it's been an actual (uncommon) verb since the 14th century. In fairness, though, a lot of those uses are using the word in its modern sense as *to be covered and infected with [an alien symbiote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venom_(character)) similar to [Eddie Brock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Brock)'s, providing additional strength and powers while corrupting one's mind*, which the OED hasn't gotten around to adding yet.

**If we're doing Substance Noun:Past-Tense Verb for Afflicting With**, then [Mr Fink's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/158844/171986) is 95% right:

### **Poison:Poisoned::Venom:[Buncha Stuff]**

You can say *Bob poisoned Mike's food* to mean *Bob put poison in Mike's food* and use something else to describe what happened to Mike himself, but the most common way to express that is *Bob poisoned Mike*. However, [by far, the common thing to do when an animal gets its venom into another animal is to use the verb that describes the specific way that happened](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snake+bit+him%2C+snake+poisoned+him%2C+snake+venomed+him%2C+snake+envenomed+him%2C+snake+envenomated+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3): *The snake bit the Australian*... *The spider bit the Australian*... *The jellyfish stung the Australian*... *The bee stung the Australian*... *The other snake blinded the Australian by shooting its venom into his eyes*... &c. The other thing [that happens a non-0% of the time](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22snake+poisoned+him%22) is to use *poisoned*, not [*venomed*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22snake+venomed+him%22) or [*envenomed*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22snake+envenomed+him%22) which *are* used effectively 0% of the time. The sole examples Google knows of only consist of Redditors telling other Redditors that no one ever uses those words that way.

**If we're doing Substance Noun:Covered-With Adjective**, then [Choster's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57096/171986) isn't wrong but it's not the best either.

### **Poison:Poisoned::Venom:Poisoned**

[It's more common in English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=venomed+sword%2Cenvenomed+sword%2Cenvenomated+sword&year_start=1800&year_end=2019) to say a Danish sword or Russian umbrella was [*envenomed* or *envenom'd*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/63060) by someone than *venomed* or *empoisoned* by them. Outside of metered poetry, many speakers would parse *venomed* as somehow meaning the item had been bioengineered to produce and secrete its own toxin. [People are much more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=envenomed+sword%2Cpoisoned+sword&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) to describe such an item as *poisoned*, though, even if it makes some listeners think for a second or two of the sword or umbrella sweating and vomiting while sick in bed.

In the same way, **if we're doing Substance Noun:Afflicted-With Adjective**, **which I *think* is what OP meant**, then so far no one has said it outside of comments like FumbleFinger's and Oldcat's:

### **Poison:Poisoned::Venom:Poisoned**

*Mike was poisoned by the hipster IPA Bob substituted for his Bud Lite. Also the arsenic.* *The Australian, letting his guard down whilst on holiday, was poisoned by the asp's venom*. [The other possible options aren't even a blip on the radar](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+poisoned+by+the+snake%2Cwas+venomed+by+the+snake%2Cwas+envenomed+by+the+snake%2Cwas+envenomated+by+the+snake%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), regardless of what toxicologists and middle-school biology teachers might pretend is more proper.

Finally, if we were doing Substance Noun:Past-Tense Verb for Evolutionarily Developed, then [Ruakh's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57127/171986) would be a correct one but that sense would be off-topic since the first part no longer works. Poison:[N/A]::Venom:Envenomated. Species that have developed venom *are* sometimes described as *envenomated*, but *no* species that has developed poison is described as *poisoned* to discuss that process. The process is sometimes described as *toxification* and *intoxification*, but no one uses *toxificated* and *intoxicated* obviously means something else entirely. The analogue *empoisoned* has only been used for literally and figuratively adding poison to other things. The only verb that *kind of* matches envenomated here is *toxified*, but cursory googling only finds scientists using it to describe organisms that are poisoned or cause poison because of various forms of pollution (mercury, aluminum, &c.) that make them ill or toxic for human consumption. That obviously differs from the gradual evolutionary process of starting to develop your own poison as a form of protection or aid to predation.

Answer (score -4):

**Venomous**  - For example, a venomous snake.

Comment: *poison* is to *poisoned* as *venom* is to *venomous*? I don't think so...

Comment: Well, certainly not venomed. Not in modern usage. Poison and Venom are both nouns. Poisoned could be the simple past or the past participle. In the present case, it appears to be the past participle, which can also serve as an adjective. For practical purposes, its use as the past participle is very limited. Thus, I'd treat it as an adjective. If we accept "poisoned" as an adjective (poisoned minds), then we can equally accept venomous as a corresponding adjective (venomous minds).

Comment: @Jack: Good point about the "adjectival" use. As for the past tense verb, the short answer is you're [poisoned by venom](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22poisoned%20by%20snake%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22poisoned+by+venom%22&psj=1&oq=%22poisoned+by+venom%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=11018l13958l0l14228l10l10l0l0l0l0l101l651l9.1l10l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=1e0e72d07edee1f3&biw=1305&bih=800)

Comment: @Jack: The OP has specifically mentioned (in the comments) that he was talking about the illness (i.e. poisoned = rendered ill by poison)

Comment: you're poisoned by venom - Good application. But that's the past participle. You used it with the auxiliary verb "to be", which is used to form the passive in conjunction with the past participle. The real question, therefore, is: How did their minds become poisoned (venomous)?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan - That doesn't change the fact that a venomous mind and a poisoned mind are one and the same. Both arise from an illness (i.e. venomous = rendered ill by venom).

Comment: @Jack Robbin: I don't know about you, but if I heard *"Jack has a venomous mind"* I'd interpret this as with *venomous snake* - to mean he might poison others with his evil mind, not that he himself has been thus injured by someone else.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - If he has a venomous mind, he must be ill, infected by and suffering from venom. The same holds true for a poisoned mind. In either case, one would be wary of the poison or venom likely to be spewing from that mind. As I see it, you've locked onto "poisoned" as a passive state, past participle. However, if you grasp its function as an adjective, you'll recognize it as an active agent in influencing its environment.

Comment: @Jack Robbin: A *venomous mind* conflates with a *poisonous mind* - as one which is liable to visit evil on others. The same might be true of a *poisoned mind*, but in the former cases it makes more sense to assume we're dealing with someone congenitally evil, whereas the latter suggests a mind which has been turned to evil by some external force. I accept that in practice the nature/nurture problem may render this distinction moot in many such contexts. But I honestly can't equate a *venomous snake* with a *poisoned snake* - and after all, that's the meaning OP is asking for.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Many people, evidently you among them, see snakes as inherently evil. Humans, on the other hand, are considered to be born innocent. Those are simply handy prejudices and by no means objective facts. In an alternative narrative, snakes may be viewed as poisoned and humans as venomous in the sense you imply. As such, conceivably, the venomous snake may be as poisoned as the venomous human mind.

Comment: I certainly don't *actually* consider snakes to be inherently evil, though in order to understand what people often mean in common parlance, we all sometimes have to acknowledge that perception. I don't believe in the biblical myth of the Garden of Evil either, but I need to acknowledge it to understand "forbidden fruit", obviously. My point is simply that a grass-snake, for example, could be *poisoned*, but never *poisonous*. A human mind, on the other hand, could be either, neither, or both.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - If a human mind may be, as you term it: "...either, neither, or both." Then, on what basis do you reject the same attributes for snakes?

Comment: Erm... - because imho snakes aren't really capable of being judged by human moral values. Obviously a grass-snake has more cerebral capacity than, say, a flea or a bacterium - but I really couldn't attribute anything remotely akin to *malevolence* to such a "less-than-pea-brained" creature.

Comment: And malevolence is a synonym for?