# Is there a verb that means to inject with poison?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb that means, "to inject venom," or, "to inject poison?"

Comment: There's also "empoison", but it's archaic in its literal sense of to poison.

Comment: Is "injection" a required aspect?

Comment: An apple can be `laced with cyanide`

Comment: Do you mean injecting into a person directly, or injecting into a food or drink item?

Comment: Related: *[“Poison” is to “poisoned” as “venom” is to what?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57092)*

Comment: "Praga Khan-ed"? ;-)

Comment: If it's being injected rather than ingested, isn't it venom by definition?

Comment: @choster - That's not related; that's required reading.

Answer (score 26):

Those are two separate things.
The verb form of **poison** encompasses the latter. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poison):

> 1 a : to injure or kill with poison; 
>   b : to treat, taint, or impregnate with or as if with poison

Curiously, M-W defines **[envenom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envenom#examples)** as:

> 1 : to make poisonous

The [freedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/envenom) defines **envenom** as:

> 1. to fill or impregnate with venom; make poisonous

Comment: I'm confused by your use of "curiously". M-W and freedictionary are defining the word the same way (also how Oxford defines it). To envenom something is to make it poisonous (an envenomed object would poison someone if they ingested it or were stabbed by it, e.g.). "Envenomate", as Roger suggests, means to directly poison the person/animal in question using venom, often by biting or stinging.

Comment: @MichaelS It is my understanding that not all venom is poisonous.

Comment: @MichaelS usually you ingest poison and are stabbed by venom - you say that "an envenomed object would poison someone if they ingested it or were stabbed by it" - at least in my experience, you could stab someone with an envenomed object, but you would only ingest something that is poisoned.

Answer (score 24):

[Envenomate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/envenomate)

> (of a snake, spider, insect, etc.) poison by biting or stinging.
>
> *‘these observations suggest that the spiders envenomate their prey’*

(Oxford Living Dictionaries)

Comment: I live in Australia with lots of venomous animals, this is the term most commonly used where I am.

Answer (score 7):

The fairly archaic word **[venenate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/venenation)** might fit the bill:

> **venenation** noun
>
> ven·​e·​na·​tion | \ ˌven-ə-ˈnā-shən  \
>
> Medical Definition of venenation
>
> : the condition or process of being poisoned especially by a venom of animal origin
>
> Other Words from venenation
>
> **venenate** \ ˈven-​ə-​ˌnāt  \ verb **venenated**; **venenating**

Comment: The ngram chart for "antivenom" only recently passed up "antivenin." I was always taught antivenin, so venenate made perfect sense to me, but it's definitely on its way out!

Comment: @MichaelW. what ngram chart are you using?

Comment: @kkarakk https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=antivenom%2Cantivenin&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cantivenom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cantivenin%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

Poisoned [Cambridge Dict](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/poisoned) and [Oxford dict](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/poison) combined into 1 answer

> VERB
>   [WITH OBJECT]
>   B2 to put poison in someone's food or drink:
>
> 'He said that someone had poisoned his coffee.'
>
> 1.1 Adulterate or contaminate with poison.
>    ‘the Amazon basin is being poisoned by the mercury used by gold prospectors’

or My example from comments

> she poisoned the apple and waited for snow white to eat it

Comment: And neither are direct examples of _injecting_, which is what OP asked for.

Comment: correct, but the OP hasn't actually answered the question (from 24 hours ago) do they literally mean inject or just add.  So i added a speculative answer